# Xaml make element through two columns

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have simple grid

```
<Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    ....
```

On the last row I have `TextBlock` but I need that text block to take two columns.
Problem is that if it take just first column it stretch other three elements to right which I dont want.

Is this achievable? If yes how?

Comment: `TextBlock but I need that text block to take two columns` set the [Grid.ColumnSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan?view=netframework-4.8) on that `TextBlock`. So something along `<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan = 2 />` If this doesn't produce what you're looking for, please update your post to include reproducible steps and your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a columnspann

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan?view=windowsdesktop-6.0